# Is there a way to pass Python variables to a Plotly Dash clientside_callback?

Tags: javascript, python, plotly, plotly-dash, client-side

I am trying to make a clientside callback in Plotly Dash where a JavaScript script will be executed. I have a Python variable defined somewhere else in the script and now I want to pass that variable to the clientside callback where I have my script. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
python_variable = 'string or some variable'

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(n_clicks, user_input) {
        if (n_clicks){
            alert(%{user_input} + %{python_variable});
        }
    }
    """,
    Output('dummy_div', 'children'),
    [Input('btn', 'n_clicks'),
     Input('user_input', value)]
```

I do not know how to put my python_variable in a dcc.Store as I load variables during page load (have no callback for this). Is it possible to add my Python variable to my clientside callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pass the variable to the `data` property of a `dcc.Store` component in the layout.

Then you can just add the `Store` components' `data` property to the callback as a `State`.

MWE:

```
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

python_variable = "string or some variable"

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Input(id="input", value="", type="text"),
        html.Div(id="output"),
        dcc.Store(id="store", data=python_variable),
    ]
)

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(input, python_variable) {
        return `${python_variable}: ${input}`
    }
    """,
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("input", "value"),
    State("store", "data"),
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```